# How to select static values on mysql select query?

Tags: mysql

I am new to mysql, here i am trying to get data from database table.

```
select id,txnid,amount,status from txn_details;
```

With above query Getting data successfully but `status` column getting `0` or `1` or `2`, but i want `0` as `failed`, `1` as `success` and `2` as `not processed`.

How to change my query?

Comment: If you have a lot of status values or they are subject to change and you don't want to discover and recode your queries I would create a separate table , possibly timestamped, for them and use a join to get the values.

Comment: @P.Salmon yes lot of status here.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `case`

```
select id, txnid, amount,
       case when status = 0 then 'failed'
            when status = 1 then 'success'
            else 'not processed'
       end as status
from txn_details;
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use an expression in the SELECT list. It could be a searched `CASE` expression  e.g.

```
SELECT CASE t.status 
         WHEN 0 THEN 'failed' 
         WHEN 1 THEN 'success'
         WHEN 2 THEN 'not processed'
         ELSE 'unknown' 
       END AS status_name
     , t.status
     , t.amount
     , t.txnid
  FROM txn_details t
```

This approach is ANSI-92 standards compliant, and will work in most relational databases.

There are some other MySQL specific alternatives, such as the `ELT` function ...

```
SELECT ELT(t.status+1,'failed','success','not processed') AS status_name 
     , t.status
     , t.amount
     , t.txnid
  FROM txn_details t
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_elt

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer a central point of maintenance (ie you prefer not to recode all your queries when a new status comes along) you could create a status table and either use a join or sub query to get the values, alternatively you could create a function, for example

```
drop table if exists txn_details,txn_status;

create table txn_details(id int, txnid int, amount int , status int);
insert into txn_details values
(1,1,10,1),(2,1,10,2),(3,1,10,4);

create table txn_status (id int, statusval varchar(20));
insert into txn_status values
(1,'success'),(2,'not processed'), (3,'failed');

drop function if exists f;
delimiter $$

create function f(instatus int)
returns varchar(20)
begin
declare rval varchar(20);
return  (select
                case when instatus = 1 then 'success'
                        when instatus = 2 then 'not processed'
                        when instatus = 3 then 'failed'
                        else 'Unknown'
                end
             );


select t.*,coalesce(ts.statusval,'Unknown') status
from txn_details t
left join txn_status ts on ts.id = t.status;

select t.*,coalesce((select statusval from txn_status ts where ts.id = t.status),'Unknown') status
from txn_details t;
```

Note the use of coalesce in case a status is not found.
Both produce this result

```
+------+-------+--------+--------+---------------+
| id   | txnid | amount | status | status        |
+------+-------+--------+--------+---------------+
|    1 |     1 |     10 |      1 | success       |
|    2 |     1 |     10 |      2 | not processed |
|    3 |     1 |     10 |      4 | Unknown       |
+------+-------+--------+--------+---------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Using the function like this

```
select t.*, f(status) as status
from txn_details t;
```

also produces the same result.

Of course using a status table or a function means you have to communicate their availability and enforce their use.

I would also consider the using a foreign key constraint in txn_details to cut down on the number of unknown values and put procedures in place to stop people adding new status codes at will without going through change control

Answer (score -1):

The following query would work. It uses `CASE ... END` to determine and return values for the virtual column `status`.

```
SELECT id,txnid,amount,
    CASE
        WHEN status = 0 THEN 'failed'
        WHEN status = 1 THEN 'success'
        WHEN status= 2 THEN 'not processed'
    END AS status
FROM txn_details;
```